# I'm going to start npm and I'm getting the following error message

Tags: reactjs, npm

```
⠋ building schema
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! react-website@0.0.1 dev: `gatsby develop -H 0.0.0.0`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the react-website@0.0.1 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\enssel\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-07-11T02_36_02_851Z-debug.log
```

Removed cache and reinstalled `npm` package, but not effective.

I did as follows. `npm start dev`

[image]

Comment: What is your node and npm version?

Comment: Can you check port number, if it's already in use? Second, can you check the complete log in the file `C:\Users\enssel\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-07-11T02_36_02_851Z-debug.log`?

Comment: Post your `package.json` file here. Also give a try to `npm start` only.

Answer (score 0):

It is a conflicted port. Just update your webpack.config.js and set port manually.

```
   devServer: {
     historyApiFallback: true,
     contentBase: './',
     port: 3000 // <--- Add this line and choose your own port number
   }
```

See this [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/StephenGrider/ReduxSimpleStarter/issues/118#issuecomment-302857942).